# If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, and $f$ and $g$ have the same domain/codomain, must $f$ and $g$ also be one-to-one?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one for the functions $f : A \to B$ and $g : A \to B$, must both $g$ and $f$ also be one-to-one?

Normally, when $f$ and $g$ have different domains/codomains, only $f$ must be one-to-one. However, if both $g$ and $f$ have the same domain/codomain, and their composition is one-to-one, must $g$ also be one-to-one? My intuition tells me yes, but I wasn't able to work out a formal proof.

Any input for why g would/wouldn't have to be one-to-one would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can't form $g\circ f$ with $g$ and $f$ as given...

Comment: That is, unless $A=B$, $g\circ f$ doesn't make sense if both $f$ and $g$ go from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A = [-1,1]$, $f:A \to A,\, f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$ and $g:A\to A, \, g(x)=x^2$.
Then $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, but $g$ is not.

Comment: This provides a valid example, so I deleted my post!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!